# Sorting plist by location

Tags: ios, objective-c, gps

I'm completely new to `Objective-C` and `iOS Development` which I am trying to teach myself. I have a book that I'm following and one of the first things it teaches you is how to populate a `TableView` with `plist` items in a Master/Detail type of layout. I thought it would be an interesting task to get the users gps location (which I did figure out how to do) and then sort a `plist` of various gps locations based on how close they are to the user in descending order. My initial thought was to put those values into an `Array` and then iterate though that Array and compare the locations 1 by 1. My problem is I have looked though this book and various Google searches and I can't figure out how to accomplish this. Any hints or examples would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have your CLLocation objects in an array (called arr in my example) and you have the users location (self.myLocation in my example), you can sort them using sortedArrayUsingComparator:.

```
NSArray *sorted = [self.arr sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(CLLocation *obj1, CLLocation *obj2) {
        if ([obj1 distanceFromLocation:self.myLocation] > [obj2 distanceFromLocation:self.myLocation]) {
            return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
        }else if ([obj1 distanceFromLocation:self.myLocation] < [obj2 distanceFromLocation:self.myLocation]){
            return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
        }else{
            return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
        }
    }];
```

Comment: Now I have the locations hardcoded in the plist as an array containing 2 numbers (lat and long) how will I get those to compare to the current location

Comment: @rsay3, that will make things much harder -- comparing two CLLocation objects takes into account the curvature of the earth, which won't be easy to do with individual lat and lon values. If all the locations are reasonably close together, you could just use the pythagorean theorem to calculate the distances.